# Select2 truncated Chinese characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for select form in the Rails app. In select form, select2 generated an input field with class name is "**select2-search__field**". When I input Latin characters into it, it is normal, but if I input the Chinese characters, the search text will be truncated. Example: I type **老师您好**, the search will be **老师您**. How can I solve this problem. Please help me any suggestion you have.

Comment: Add the rails version and version of select2 to your question